# Regex to remove carriage return followed by space

Tags: c#, regex

Relatively new to regex, but hoping someone can help. While I've seen loads of examples on how to remove certain characters or combinations of characters, I can't seem to get the following to work for me.

I have a file with the following lines:

```
a b c
d
ef
 g h
i
```

What I need is to end up with a string that removes the exact occurrance of newline and space (and only that), so the result would be

```
a b c
d
efg h
i
```

Right now I have

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText("input.text");
string result = Regex.Replace(contents,@"[\n \r]\ ","");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

but that only removes the space in front of the g h line, instead of also combining it with the previous line.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, do not include a languge tag in a title unless it wouldn't made sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Thans, will remember in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string text = Regex.Replace( contents, @"(\r|\n)+^ +", "" , RegexOptions.None | RegexOptions.Multiline );
```

Mine reads as:

One or more matches of \r or \n (new line characters) --> "(\r|\n)+"

followed by the beginning of a line --> "^"

followed by one or more spaces --> " +"

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(contents,@"(?s)(?:(?:\r|\n)+ +)","");
```

`(?s)` Is to utilise singlie line mode.

Comment: Thanks, but this gives exactly the same result: The space before g is removed (as it should be), but "g h" is still on its own line, while I need it 'moved up' and appended to the one before it, as well.

Comment: Thanks, I see it's different now, but in the meantime Derek below gave another working alternative. Thanks again.